# Chrome Extension-ManifestV3-"Error: Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist." How do i send msg from bkgd to content?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

**SOLVED**: see my answer below

I am *attempting* to learn how to pass data between files in a Chrome Extension. My goal is to query data from the dom of a site when a particular url loads. Then display the queried data in a popup. I am having trouble with passing information the order of message events for the content, popup, background script.

What I believe is the right course of action:

1. Background script determines if tab is the correct site via url comparison
2. Background sends message to content script, via `chrome.tab.message`
3. Content script receives message via `chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener()`, and performs information gathering from the site's dom.
4. Content script sends results via `chrome.runtime.sendMessage` to popup script to populate information in popup.html

> I can see the console.log of the background.js by inspecting the popup. However, I get Uncaught (in promise) Error: Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist.

and no further console.logs in either the web page or popup dev tools console.

**file structure**

```
root/
├─ manifest.json
├─ background.js
├─ popup/
│  ├─ popup.html
│  ├─ popup.js
└─ scripts/
   └─ content.js
```

**manifest.json**

```json
{
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "name": "Plex File Name Generator",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "description": "Generate file name for Plex from IMDb",
    "permissions": ["tabs"],
    "host_permissions": ["https://*.imdb.com/tt*"],
    "background": {
        "service_worker": "background.js"
    },
    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "matches": ["https://*.imdb.com/tt*"],
            "js": ["scripts/content.js"]
        }
    ],
    "action": {
        "default_icon": {
            "16": "assets/ext-icon.png",
            "24": "assets/ext-icon.png",
            "32": "assets/ext-icon.png"
        },
        "default_title": "Plex File Name Generator",
        "default_popup": "popup/popup.html"
    }
}
```

**popup.html**

```html
<script type="module" src="popup.js"></script>

<div class="container">
    <div class="title">Plex File Name Generator</div>
</div>
```

**popup.js**

```js
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((obj, sender, response) => {
    const { type, movieTitle, imdbId } = obj;
    if (type === "displayMovieTitle") {
        console.log("popup", movieTitle, imdbId);
    }
});
```

**content.js**

```js
(() => {
    chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((request, sender, response) => {
        const { type, imdbId } = request;

        if (type === "getMovieInfo") {
            const titleSpan = document.querySelector(
                'h1[data-testid="hero__pageTitle"] > span'
            );
            const movieTitle = titleSpan?.innerText?.trim() || "";

            chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ type: "displayMovieTitle", movieTitle, imdbId });
        }
        return true;
    });
})();
```

**background.js**

```js
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener((tabId, tab) => {
    if (tab.url?.includes("imdb.com/title/tt")) {
        chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener((nextTabId, nextTab) => {
            if (tabId === nextTabId && nextTab.status === "complete") {
                const imdbId = tab.url.match(/tt\d+/g)?.[0] || "";

                chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabId, {
                    type: "getMovieInfo",
                    imdbId,
                });
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: I think the moderators will close this question as it already exists.

Answer (score 1):

Solved: My matching pattern for content scripts was incorrect.
**wrong**

```
"content_scripts": [
    {
        "matches": ["https://*.imdb.com/title/tt*"], //instead of "matches": ["https://*.imdb.com/tt*"],
        "js": ["scripts/content.js"]
    }
],
```

Realized if I put an alert in the content script, it didnt show up. And could not find the script in the site's dom. Turns out it was never injected.